# Is there an api in Google maps sdk to determine a location's category like restauraunt or Hotel etc?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm developing an android app from which I'm getting the current location of the user.
When a user visits a place, I would like to find if the place is a Hotel or a Motel or a temple and record the frequency of the user's visit on each category.

Answer (score 0):

Google APi already has information about this:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

There is a good explanation on how to search and parse out location types.